# Syncing RTSP Audio and Video

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I am using command line ffmpeg for windows. I have an Axis IP camera and an Axis Network I/O Module. https://www.axis.com/nl-nl/products/axis-p8221

The IP camera sends video stream over RTSP. While the Axis Network I/O module sends audio over RTSP. The video and audio are not synchronised. Any ideas how I can get the audio and video synchronised?

Thanks in advance.